# How to record a video and watch it using .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, camera, maui

I am using .NET MAUI to create a cross-platform app. And I am using `Camera.MAUI` to create an app page with a camera preview and have an image button that is intended so that if the user clicks the button, the app starts recording and if the user clicks again, the app stops recording.

What I am planning is that once the user is done recording, the app will automatically navigate the user to another page, where it shows the taken video.

I know in order to record a video and stop recording, I need to use `StartRecordingAsync` and `StopRecordingAsync` method. But right after I used `StopRecordingAsync` I put the following code to see if the taken video is stored correctly but it always say "File NOT found at ---" meaning the video is not stored at the fileName I created.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"File found at {fileName}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"File NOT found at {fileName}");
                }
```

This is the snippet that I have. Basically if someone starts recording, the `if` block works and if someone stops recording, the `else` block works.

Also I put two debug statements `Debug.WriteLine("before recording result " + result);` and `Debug.WriteLine("Start recording result " + result);`. And the result returns to be "Success" before recording and then it always return "AccessDenied" after starting to record even though I am sure I put in all the necessary permissions to use the camera and record a video. I'm using Android and I put permission for CAMERA, RECORD_AUDIO, and RECORD_VIDEO in the Android Manifest file.

```
private string fileName = string.Empty;

var result = CameraResult.Success;
if (!isRecordingVideo)
            {
                if (await RequestPermissions())
                {
                    // Create a unique file name
                    var uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var fileName = $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}_{uniqueId}.mp4";
                    // Get the cache directory path and ensure it exists
                    var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                    
                    // Combine the directory path with the file name
                    fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

                    // Start video recording
                    result = await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(fullPath);

                    Debug.WriteLine("Start recording result " + result);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = CameraResult.AccessDenied;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Request Permission status: " + result);
                }

            }
```

I think it says the file cannot be found because it wasn't recorded in the first place but I don't understand why it keeps saying "AccessDenied" Below is the documentation I used but I don't know where I can find any information about what I'm looking for.

https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a path as shown in the docs

```
var result = await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "Video.mp4", new Size(1920, 1080)));
....
result = cameraView.StopRecordingAsync();
```

in your update, you are calling `Path.Combine` **three times** which results in a bad path

```
// here you are calling Path.Combine twice
// this probably is OK, but uneccessary
videoFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, fileName));

// later you call it again, this time you
// do end up with an invalid path
result = await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, videoFilePath));
```

instead you should use the path you already built

```
result = await cameraView.StartRecordingAsync(videoFilePath);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason. I added the code that supplies the path but it didn't work. I used a debug statement `Debug.WriteLine("Start recording result " + result);` right after `StartRecordingAsync` method and it says AccessDenied as a result. I'm using Android and am sure that I put all the permissions in the `AndroidManifest` file. Do you have any clue why it says AccessDenied?

Comment: I don't see any code where you are supplying a path, just a file name.  Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=android) on file system access in MAUI

Comment: I meant that I added it after your comment and it didn't work as when I debug, it says AccessDenied

Comment: please edit your question to show the change you made.  I can't help you if I don't know what you've tried

Comment: you are calling `Path.Combine` **three times**.  This is going to result in an invalid path.

Comment: see my last update

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I thought that would be the reason why it didn't work so I deleted the `Path.Combine` and only used it once but still it doesn't let me record because the debug statement keeps returning to be `AccessDenied`.

Comment: is it prompting you for permissions?  It appears that error could happen if it fails to get permissions for Camera, StorageWrite, or Microphone

Comment: That is what I thought too. But I did put permission for `android.permission.CAMERA`, `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`, and `android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO` but any time I use `StartRecordingAsync`, the variable I assign it to returns `AccessDenied`. And the confusing part is nowhere in `StartRecordingAsync` code makes a variable return `AccessDenied`.

Comment: https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI/blob/d9ee42a428b9ee41efff624fe01643b62c7781e6/Camera.MAUI/Platforms/Android/MauiCameraView.cs#L200

Comment: Thank you for the link. Seems like my storage write permission is denied. but even though I put `var results = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();` the app doesn't ask permission at all and just assume it is denied. is there another way to ask for this permission? I'm using Android 13.0 (API level 33).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it is the permissions of Android 13, what I did was change the target Android version (12), it is not the best solution but in the meantime I am doing it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35331080)